# Finding the content length of a multipart image

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to submit a multipart image to a post request and I am frequently getting a "414 Request-URI Too Large" error when trying to post it. I'm wondering if my headers for submitting the photo are incorrect, because I noticed that most posts require content-length, boundaries, etc.

I'm wondering if some of that parameters are supposed to be auto filled or if I'm supposed to submit them myself.

This is a snippet of my code that can give an example of what I'm doing

```
with open(imageFile, 'rb') as f:
    headers = {"Authorization": "Token mytoken", "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
    r = requests.post('https://api.findface.pro/v1/detect', params={"photo": f},headers=headers)
```

Sorry if this post isn't formatted correctly, this is my first post on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The image (as a multipart data) can't be sent trough an url parameter.

In your example the "post" request would be this->
https://api.findface.pro/v1/detect/

You should send the data this way to the server:

```
with open(imageFile, 'rb') as file:
    headers = {"Authorization": "Token mytoken",
               "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}

    data = {'photo': file}
    r = requests.post('https://api.findface.pro/v1/detect', data = data,headers=headers)
```